# Match all words from string in another string (words can be in different positions)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-apply

I have a list of strings that I have to match with dataframe column.

The list looks as follows:

```
list = ['golden village lte', 'pones wcdma', 'coral gbts', 'street view gbts', 'street view
wcdma']
```

The column in the dataframe looks like this:

```
data = {'COLUMN': ['wcdma street view disconnected', 'gbts planned work street view', 'lte atn golden village optical invalid', 'wcdma street view planned work']}
```

I'd like to find every row which contains each word from the sting from list so that as a result I could have the next dataframe:

```
  COLUMN                               |  String    
 wcdma street view disconnected        | street view wcdma  
 gbts planned work street view         | street view gbts  
 lte atn golden village optical invalid| golden village lte  
 wcdma street view planned work        | street view wcdma
```

What did I tried to find matches is to provide string in list as list of elements (like ['street', 'view', 'wcdma']) and do searches:

```
df.apply(lambda x: all(er in x.COLUMN for er in list), axis=1)
```

But it returns me nothing, even in case I do know that there must be at least one match. It WILL return smth if I change all() to any() but that's not what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
list2 = ['golden village lte', 'pones wcdma', 'coral gbts', 'street view gbts', 'street view wcdma']
list2=[x.split(' ') for x in list1]
data = {'COLUMN': ['wcdma street view disconnected', 'gbts planned work street view', 'lte atn golden village optical invalid', 'wcdma street view planned work']}
data=pd.DataFrame(data)
def search(x):
    list1=x.split(' ')
    for y in list2:
         check=all(item in list1 for item in y)
         if check:
             return ' '.join(y)
    return None
data['matched']=data['COLUMN'].transform(search)
```

Explanation: I am converting each string as list 1st splitting on space. Using transform() for 'COLUMN', I am using all() to detect whether all elements of 'y' are in 'list2'. If yes, I return that string

Comment: worked like a charm, thanks! {although I'm still curious what's wrong with my code...}

Comment: I myself trying to figure out the same!!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'COLUMN': ['wcdma street view disconnected', 'gbts planned work street view', 'lte atn golden village optical invalid', 'wcdma street view planned work']})
df

                                   COLUMN
0          wcdma street view disconnected
1           gbts planned work street view
2  lte atn golden village optical invalid
3          wcdma street view planned work
```

Now, use [**`df.apply`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

```
lst = ['golden village lte', 'pones wcdma', 'coral gbts', 'street view gbts', 'street view wcdma']  
df['String'] = df.COLUMN.apply(lambda x:[i for i in lst if all(j in x for j in i.split())].pop())
df
                                   COLUMN              String
0          wcdma street view disconnected   street view wcdma
1           gbts planned work street view    street view gbts
2  lte atn golden village optical invalid  golden village lte
3          wcdma street view planned work   street view wcdma
```